# Capitalize every file in a directory, in bash, using 'svn mv'

Tags: svn, shell, file, batch-file, rename

I need to change the capitalization of a set of files in a subversion working copy, like so:

```
svn mv test.txt Test.txt
svn mv test2.txt Test2.txt
svn mv testn.txt Testn.txt
...
svn commit -m "caps"
```

How can I automate this process? Standard linux install tools available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ls | awk '{system("svn mv " $0 " " toupper(substr($0,1,1)) substr($0,2))}'

obviously, other scripting languages will work just as well.  awk has the advantage that it it ubiquitous.

Comment: Perfect, just the one liner I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a decent install you should have python, give this a try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import rename, listdir
path = "/path/to/folder"
try:
    dirList = listdir(path)
except:
    print 'There was an error while trying to access the directory: '+path
for name in dirList:
    try:
        rename(path+'\\'+name, path+'\\'+name.upper())
    except:
        print 'Process failed for file: '+name
```

Comment: name.capitalize(), not upper()

Comment: that will depend on what is wanted, if he wants "Filename" then yes you are correct however I assumed "FILENAME" was wanted in which case I am correct.

Comment: If you read his question, it would be clear that he wanted "Filename" rather than "FILENAME", however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think theres an easy way to do it with  bash/sed/tr/find.

I'd make a Ruby/Perl script that does the renaming.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby 
 #  Upcase.rb 
 ARGV.each{ |i|
  newname = i.gsub(/(^.|\s.)/{ |x| x.upcase }
  `svn mv "#{i}" "#{newname}" `
 }
```

Then just do

```
 ./Upcase.rb foo.txt test.txt test2.txt foo/bar/test.txt
```

or if you want to do a whole dir

```
 find ./ -exec ./Upcase.rb {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this change breaks existing workingcopies on Windows and Mac systems, as they can't handle case only renames.

Comment: On Subversion <= 1.6 this broke working copies. With >= 1.7 an update bringing in case changes might note some obstructions, but you can recover from this state without having your working copy broken.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this by redirecting the 'ls' output to a file, using vim macros to massage each filename into the command line I want, then execute the file as a shell script. It's crude but effective.